# How to exclude Android resources for a particular resource qualifier

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

Suppose I have the following resources in my Android project:

- `res/values/strings.xml`
- `res/values-land/strings.xml`

I would like to exclude the resources defined for `land` qualifier from packaging into apk. Is there such a possibility?
And, no, I can not just remove the `res/values-land/`, as it's required for some flavors.

I tried several options, like using the `sourceSets.main.res.filter.exclude` or `packagingOptions`, but no success.

Comment: "as it's required for some flavors." - so add it just to those flavors?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, it's long story, but I can't due to other reasons.

Comment: Can you explain those reasons?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I agree with you the request sounds odd and it implies there's a deeper root issue. It would be right to declare alternative resources for those flavors, but the project is big and this kind of refactoring would take a lot of time, so I got a request to investigate this option as the most cheap workaround.

Looks like there is no support in AGP out of the box (I don't consider crazy ways to do that), so we'll apply a true way as you mentioned.